# Unable to login application as different user Selenium WebDriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

1) I have tried passing username and password in URL(ex: "https://username:password@domain.com"). We are able to login with different user successfully, but facing some issues like error as `"Unable to construct URL"` in browser console.

2) In other way I tried with the below code, that did not work for me. Please help how to login as different user using chrome profile.

```
ChromeOption options=new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("user-data-dir = C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default")
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToURL(baseURL);
```

Comment: If you manually copy paste `baseURL` into the browser will it login as you expect?

Comment: When baseURL entered in the browser, It will login as current user. But expected to login with different user in the chrome browser.